# JavaScript expandable treeview lightweight

Tags: javascript, css, treeview

I wanted a lightweight solution so i found this one, however it only expands on clicking plus sign "+" next to the name of expandable category. I replaced + for red square and - for blue square for this demonstration to work.
Live code at: http://jsfiddle.net/2VXuk/2/

I need help modifying it to make any sub level that is expandable to be category that's not a link and upon clicking on its name expand its content.

Would be great to have option to make it a category - expand on click or link expand on + click and redirect on name click.
e.g.

```
<ul id="sitemap">
<li><a class="category" href="#">expands only</a> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
        <li><a class="category_and_link" href="psy.html">Link to page or expand on + button</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
            </ul>                           
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fifth link</a></li>
    </ul>                   
</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
this.sitemapstyler = function(){
    var sitemap = document.getElementById("sitemap")
    if(sitemap){

        this.listItem = function(li){
            if(li.getElementsByTagName("ul").length > 0){
                var ul = li.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
                ul.style.display = "none";
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.className = "collapsed";
                span.onclick = function(){
                    ul.style.display = (ul.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
                    this.className = (ul.style.display == "none") ? "collapsed" : "expanded";
                };
                li.appendChild(span);
            };
        };

        var items = sitemap.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            listItem(items[i]);
        };

    };  
};

window.onload = sitemapstyler;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [fork of your jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AF7DX/3/) The basic idea is to grab the `a` element...

```
var a = li.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

and add an event handler to it as well.

```
if (!a.hasAttribute("href"))
    a.onclick = showHide;
```

For non-links, just leave out the `href` attribute.

Comment: I dont see its working as desired i click on "First link" (words not box) and it does not expand it...

Comment: @redacted My bad, forgot to hit "Update". Try the new link.

Comment: Great job, however could you please explain how i can modify so it does not expand before going to page if category is link i hardly know javascript.

Comment: Also what means [0] in "li.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]"

Comment: @redacted I updated the jsFiddle to do so. `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. `arr[0]` grabs the first element in an array.